# How to get Standard Deviation from each components in sklearn GMM after fit?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gmm

How to get Standard Deviation from each components in sklearn GMM after fit?

```
model.fit(dataSet)
model.means_ is the means of each components.
model.weights_ is the co-efficient of each components.
```

Where I can find the standard deviations of each Gaussian components?

Comment: You can get the covariance matrix using `model.covariances_` which contains the information that you're after.

Comment: Can you able to elaborate  an bit more ?

Comment: It depends on the covariance structure you've used in your model and exactly what you're trying to do. If you can update your questions with a MWE and a bit more detail I can try to help.

Comment: A table of random values (sampled from two Gaussian distributions) is provided in:  https://drive.google.com/openid=1LIGIpq96Bkg_z6TGtEaTv0y1Q2sjipZ4  What are the standard deviations of the two Gaussians
from which the sample data is drawn?

Comment: That link is dead. Also can you make sure that you edit your question, it makes the question and answer much easier to read for other. Sorry I know this is a pain, but if your Gaussians are 10 dimensional then standard deviation doesn't really mean anything, so it's best to be super clear and give code to either generate dummy data or a link to actual data.

Comment: updated link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1e-mwPZwjQ4QgfNV8H5A6-lSH7nLoFN8q?usp=sharing

Comment: Your data in 1 dimensional, so `model.covariances_` will just return the variance of each component.

Comment: Thank you , Is it possible to find the relative proportion of these two mixture ?